# How to ensure screen space derivatives are present on triangle edges?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I draw an anti-aliased rounded square as ground plane for models to sit on top using the following vertex shader:

```
#version 330
out vec2 tex;
uniform mat4 mvp;

const vec2 pos[4] = vec2[](
    vec2(-1.0, 1.0),
    vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    vec2(1.0, -1.0),
    vec2(-1.0, -1.0));

void main()
{
    tex = pos[gl_VertexID];
    /* setup camera */
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(pos[gl_VertexID], 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And the following fragment shader:

```
#version 330
in vec2 tex;
out vec4 Out_Color;

float roundedBoxSDF(vec2 uv, float Size, float Radius)
{
    return length(max(abs(uv) - Size + Radius, 0.0)) - Radius;
}

void main()
{
    /* 95% to make sure there is a screen space derivative present to
    calculate against. */
    float dist = roundedBoxSDF(tex, 0.95, 0.5);
    float smoothedAlpha = dist / length(vec2(dFdx(dist), dFdy(dist)));

    Out_Color = vec4(vec3(1, 1, 1), 1.0 - smoothedAlpha);
}
```

If I draw said square with texture coordinates right up to the edge of the quad, the non-round edges along the quad's side are always aliased, because the signed distance field has no screen space derivative to calculate against the edge with distance 1 away from the origin.

[image]

Seems like an easy fix: As already in the fragment shader above, I simply shrink the texture coordinates to 95% `roundedBoxSDF(tex, 0.95, 0.5);`, so there is a quad without edge to gather the screen space derivative against. Nicely anti-aliased...

[image]

...until I zoom far out out or view at an oblique angle. Then the 5% margin is not enough anymore and I get aliasing again, because screen-space wise there is no pixel present to get said derivative.

[image]

How can I account for something like this? Continue shrinking the texture coordinates and growing the vertices as a function of distance from the camera? Is there anything smarter than that?

Comment: I don't really understand the point of the derivative here.

Comment: @NicolBolas Is is used in the snippet `length(vec2(dFdx(dist), dFdy(dist)));` to get anti-aliasing of the edges. Without it, the signed distance field is either evaluated to be present or not present, resulting in heavy aliasing.

Comment: I see what you're doing; I don't understand *why*. If you have a distance (which is what your "distance field" is), you can just linearly interpolate between an alpha of 0 and 1 for distance values from X to Y. What is the point of derivatives here?

Comment: @NicolBolas That only works for one specific size or angle. Change the size of the quad or rotate it, then the chosen interpolation is wrong. It either becomes a huge, soft, blurry border up close or a completely aliased stair case when small or at an oblique angle.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem of "derivatives not being present". It's the result of "not enough samples", which is inevitable when you render something that small. Basically, the core concept of your algorithm is not one that is going to be resistant to aliasing. At some point, you simply need more samples. Well, I suppose you could do the equivalent of anisotropic filtering logic in your shader.

Comment: @NicolBolas If I shrink the texture space to 50% it's fine at those angles shown in the video. So it is fine with a single sample per pixel, as long as there exists fragment to derive the derivative from. I just wonder if there is something smarter than this naive shrinking.

Comment: "*as long as there exists fragment to derive the derivative from*" Derivatives exist even if you only have one fragment. And unless you use centroid sampling, they will even interpolate beyond the boundaries of the primitive. And I suggested something smarter: anisotropic filtering.

Comment: @NicolBolas _"Derivatives exist even if you only have one fragment."_ Ohh wow, I didn't know that! So clearly my setup is not optimal. I wonder how anisotropic filtering might work in the context of an SDF shader. Thx for the suggestion, will read up on this topic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with derivatives — contrary to what you believe, they are well-defined on the edges.
Nor is the lack of anisotropic filtering — because it happens at non-oblique angles too.

As you said yourself, the problem is that shrinking by 0.95 is not enough at some angles. That is because the analytical edge of your shape gets closer to the quad edge by less than a pixel. In such a case there simply isn't any pixel rasterized where a non-transparent pixel needs to be:

[image]

If you go the shrinking route, the amount you shrink itself depends on the derivatives — you need to shrink by a pixel in screen-space. An equivalent but simpler method would be to calculate the [SDF on the interior of your non-shrunk box](https://iquilezles.org/articles/distfunctions2d/), then set `out_Color.a = -smoothedAlpha`:

[image]

In either case shrinking is a rather hackish way of fixing the problem, because it changes the effective size of your shape.

The more correct way would be to dilate the rasterized triangle by a pixel. There is an NVidia extension that does exactly that: [NV_conservative_raster_dilate](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_conservative_raster_dilate.txt). In unextended OpenGL you can get similar results with a geometry shader. In either case the dilated triangles will operlap, which requires extra measures if your shape is going to be partially transparent.

Comment: Super duper in-depth with both workaround and proper fix presented. Many many thanks!
Also the linked article is a gold mine for SDF formulas, double thanks.